# NavLink activeClassName not working with Tailwind CSS

Tags: reactjs, navbar, tailwind-css, classname

I am trying to create an active class for the navbar link by the text does not change after selection. I'm just wondering where I might be going wrong.

```
        <NavLink
            exact
            to="/"
            activeClassName="text-white"
            className="inflex-flex items-center py-6 px-3 mr-4 text- 
            red-200 hover:text-green-800 text-4xl font-bold cursive 
            tracking-widest"
            activeClassName="text-black"
          >
            Home
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink
            to="/project"
            className="inline-flex items-center py-3 px-3 my-6 rounded text-red-200 hover:text-green-800"
            activeClassName="text-red-100 bg-red-700"
          >
            Projects
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink
            to="/post"
            className="inline-flex items-center py-3 px-3 my-6 rounded text-red-200 hover:text-green-800"
            activeClassName="text-red-100 bg-red-700"
          >
            Blog Posts
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink
            to="/about"
            className="inline-flex items-center py-3 px-3 my-6 rounded text-red-200 hover:text-green-800"
            activeClassName="text-red-100 bg-red-700"
          >
```

Comment: Have you checked if the component actually sets to active and classnames get applied?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing

```
activeClassName='!text-red-100 !bg-red-700'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your link's hover color is overriding the text color. You could try adding red as a hover color for the active state:

`activeClassName="text-red-100 hover:text-red-100 bg-red-700"`

Answer (score 0):

className={({ isActive }) =>
isActive ? "text-blue-700 font-bold underline" : ""
}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).